# ELI5: What is Django?

Tags: python, django

I realize that some people are probably rolling their eyes at the question, but believe it or not *"a high-level Python Web framework"* (official description) is not a really helpful sentence to a beginner.

What I know:

Python is a language where you write down stuff, and then it just gets executed from top to bottom. There are classes and objects, but its still pretty much from top to bottom. There are also libraries, which you can use with `include time` for example. Those give you a bunch of extra functions, that you don't have to write yourself. Python code is saved in `.py` files.

And now my question - is Django just a fancy python library, or is it an actuall programming language, which for some reason also uses `.py` files? And how does it work with the `{{some_variable_name}}` commands I write in my `.html` files? Is it also Django?

Please (if this question does not get removed) pretend that I am really really stupid and know absolutely nothing aside from what I just wrote.

Thanks in advance!

*More context:
I have to use [oTree](https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which is a piece of software for economic experiments. And while it is fairly simple to use as long as you don't need anything more than basic functionality, as soon as you step aside from things covered in the tutorial, you realize that it has a multitude of layers of complexity that are just COMPLETELY beyond the reach of a beginner. So I am kinda trying to unravel the mystery and at least learn the words to understand the forum answers to my questions.*

Comment: You shouldn't be asking what is Django, but what is a framework. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't think it really helps specifically here. I kinda have a vague idea about all this, but the question is worded in this veeeery simple way exactly because I want to avoid those far reaching questions and misunderstandings. Or let's put it like this: Is a programming language a framework? Or what is the difference between those? Is a Python library a framework? Those questions immediately arise when I open up the wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, a framework is a library. It's a bunch of code written elsewhere, that you use to get your stuff done.

The difference is in how much engagement you are expected to have with the actual code inside the library. With (say) the Python json module/library, you need to know absolutely nothing beyond the library call specifications. In goes a Python data structure of lists, dicts, strings and numbers. Out comes JSON text. Or vice versa. Maybe you have to decode an error message about non-serializable data and then write a serializer for, say, a Python date. Beyond that, nothing.

It's just about possible to make rudimentary / beginner level use of Django like that. Most of the books and on-line tutorials start there. But for doing most useful things, requires using Python inheritance to take Django classes and extend them to accomplish what you wish to, by overriding Django-supplied methods to insert your own code before or after calling the superclass, or occasionally to replace the Django class altogether. At all levels of a considerably deep stack, you have the option -- and almost always a desire or mission requirement --  to augment Django generic behaviour with your own more tightly linked to your own business.

There is also a vast ecosystem of modules which integrate with the Django framework. Things like django-crispy-forms, django-tables2, django-filters, and hundreds if not thousands more. These save you from reinventing numerous wheels.

Django is also, in its authors' own words, "opinionated". There is more than one way to implement a webserver. Django makes no claim to be universal. There are other frameworks. So it's "**A** high-level Python web framework", not "The only sensibly possible Python web framework".

If you prefer analogies, a straightforward library is a one-purpose machine. Say, a lawn-mower. Or even, a car. Django is more like owning an engineering works. It can make anything, within certain broad limits. It can make nothing, without somebody making decisions about "what?" and "how?", and maybe replacing some of the existing machinery with other machines better suited to the objective.

Comment: Oh wow, that actually helped a lot. I kept wondering why i don't see any "Django commands", but now I understand it a little more. I will check out my code again keeping your comments on classes in mind.

Comment: Just wanted to add something for dummies like myself: While Django is essentially "just" a huge library, some functions you can not use directly. First you may have to create specific other functions, classes or maybe even folders, and then put specifically named files in those folders. (Because the functions expect to find those folders.)